# UpdateFunctionCode in lambda does not update the code

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I have followed this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-deployment-options-for-aws-lambda/) to update the code of a lambda function using a jar file stored in a S3 bucket. the execution was succeded, but it is not updating the code of target lambda function

Code snippet

```
console.log('Loading function');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

        var functionName = "runJarFile";
        var bucket = "jarfiletest2";
        var key = "lambda-java-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.zip";

        console.log("uploaded to lambda function: " + functionName);
        var params = {
            FunctionName: functionName,
            S3Key: key,
            S3Bucket: bucket,
            Publish: true
        };
        lambda.updateFunctionCode(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                context.fail(err);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                context.succeed(data);
            }
        });
};
```

[image: Response]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to comment on this without knowing the details about the destination function. What's the output of the [GetFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_GetFunction.html) API call of that Lambda, before and after calling the `UpdateFunctionConfig` call?

I am interested to see the SHA-256 hash of the code, and the last modified timestamp off that API call before and after calling UpdateFunctionConfig:

```
{
...
    "CodeSha256": "5tT2qgzYUHoqwR616pZ2dpkn/0J1FrzJmlKidWaaCgk=",
    "LastModified": "2019-09-24T18:20:35.054+0000"
...
}
```

If the values are exactly the same, can you add this check as per the blog post to see if the bucket and the object exists?

```
if (bucket == "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME" && key == "YOUR_CODE.zip" && version) {
// your code
} else {
  context.succeed("skipping zip " + key + " in bucket " + bucket + " with version " + version);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Pls try to remove 'Publish: true' to call the latest version not the specified version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).